# Serializer is not using 100% CPU

Tags: c#, performance, serialization, protocol-buffers

Currently I'm running a few simple serialization tests. A few thousand objects are serilaized and deserialized within a loop. I noticed that this test is not using 100% cpu. Could anyone explain why?

UPDATE

I'm serializing into memory, and serialization is singlethreaded. I'm using standard .NET binary serialization and protobuf-net to compare.

Comment: code?  Also, are you sure it's not running 100% on any one core?  If your application is single threaded, you will have a max overall CPU usage of 1 / (<core count> * <cpu count>)

Comment: Are you serializing to a FileStream or MemoryStream?

Comment: How many page faults? :)

Comment: @gmagana, I checked through sysinternals proces explorer, and non of the cores is consuming 100%

Comment: @al We need to see some code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IO Operations make the thread running the serialization to block.
While it is blocked, other processes might get CPU time.

Comment: Do you mean RAM access by IO?

Comment: @Al Bundy: actually I was thinking about disk, but still, even while accessing RAM there are things that can block your thread. (Such as page faults).

Answer (score 2):

Have you got a multi-core processor? Because, if so, serialization will only use one of the cores because it's a single threaded process.

Comment: @Al Bundy: do you have a hexacore processor?

Comment: @Jesse, no it's quad. Does it make any difference?

Comment: @Al, I was just trying to see if ~18% was 100% over 6 cores (100% / 6 = ~16 2/3%).  That being the case, I'm guessing 75% of your serialization is CPU-bound while 25% is I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a multicore CPU and the serialization code is single-threaded?

Answer (score 0):

- Multi core / thread CPU?
- Memory speed overhead?
- Disk speed overhead?

Answer (score 0):

CPU's are faster as:

- Disk (even SSD)
- Network
- RAM / Memory

If you are allocating thousands of objects, you might be waiting for some page-faults.

If you are doing a de-serialization multithreaded, there might be some locking issues.